# Setting Java Environment Variables for Talend

Tags: java, talend

I'm loading Talend on my mac and I'm trying to set the Java environment variables.

Talend says to set the path based on this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_65    
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I have several issues:

1. It says I should base the 1st export on where my Java is installed which is 
   `/usr/lib/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk1.8.0_144`. I'm assuming path should be exact - so no "jvm"? Also assume my jdk is correct since that is what I have.
2. When i set the variable how do I know it takes? I've played with it and then I use `printenv` but I never see what I enter.
3. To set this perm (when I know the path) do I open terminal and enter it like this?

   `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_65 ~/ .profile`

Thanks - New to this and trying to do a little development

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. export; `printenv` is for csh. 3. Almost, no `.profile` call (that's if you edit your profile and add the `export` command - and then it will persist on login - also set it for **your** JVM, not the non-existent path).

Comment: Please go through this link https://help.talend.com/reader/UOMUtbDPR_dFAM_w4dip6Q/lMPZvSCXafXZZdxHFEHmTg

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an exact path.

Let java tell you where is it running from

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

> how do I know it takes?

You need to first `source ~/.profile` if you added it there, then you can `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Thanks - it appeared to work - now when i echo I get the path I entered.